# Can we do anything about a passage at the end of Haemar Shame

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

At the end of Haemar Shame, behind the statue, there seems to be a short cut to exit that is barred by spears.

Is there a way to use that short cut?

[image]

Comment: I"m pretty sure there is a switch, chain, or something similar to lower the spikes. Not 100% positive though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [UESP article about Haemar's Shame](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Haemar's_Shame):

> [The shortcut exit] is blocked off by 
>   spears, **with a chain on the right that lowers the spears**.